# CKeditor Copy/pasting without color & background

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I like copy past to keep links and list, but when it comes to the colors, users does not understand that it also do takes the background color, which is white and the font color, which is black.

Then, when I render it in a gray background, users do not understand why they have white background..

Is it somehow possible to keep the copy past logic but to remove the color one?